# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0 at server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have one asp.net MVC application with .NET Framework 4.0. Now in local I change my MVC version to 2.0.0.0 to 3.0.0.0 and deploy at server and I found that project not successfully deploy. When I see event logger I found the following error

> "Exception message: c:\Apps\Test\WebUI\Web.config(105): error CS0234: The type or
>   namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)"

When I see my `web.config` file i found

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
```

Search for this error and chage

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />

to 

<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
also try this
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.1" newVersion="3.0.0.1" />
```

but same error occure.
Also I see the windows/assembly and here only system.web.mvc 2.0.0.0 is present though MVC 3 is installed.

Please give me proper solution for this.

Comment: Do you have this assembly in your bin folder? In which version?

Comment: no. I have added as reference in my project but in bin folder i can't found this assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to system.web.mvc and if that's not in the reference list make sure the project target is framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

You have to have this desired assembly in your `bin` folder. If it's not there after build, simply go to your project -> Reference -> Find System.Web.Mvc -> Right-Click -> Properties -> Copy Local should be set to `true`.

Without this setting assembly won't be copied to application folder resulting in message you mentioned.

[image]

Comment: I con't find copy local option after right click on that.

Comment: @KinjalPatel - do you opened 'Properties' window for reference?

Comment: @KinjalPatel - glad I could help. Feel free to upvote and accept my answer if you wish.

Comment: @KinjalPatel - is DLL visible in you bin folder? Have you rebuilt you solution?

Comment: @KinjalPatel - and I believe you redeployed whole application?

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer:

- Expand your References folder.
- Right-click the System.Web.Mvc reference.
- Select "Properties".
- Change the "Copy Local" value to `true`.
- Rebuild.
- Redeploy.

You'll likely have to do this for a handful of assemblies, if I remember some of the PIA moments of MVC3 development correctly. Phil Haack has them listed [on his blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx/) if you want to save yourself some time figuring out which need to be adjusted. For completeness, here's the list:

- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Mvc.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

Older versions of the tooling in Visual Studio did not set the "Copy Local" property to `true`, which will add it to your `\bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use VS 12 and have found recommendation to install VS 2015 with WEB toolkit.
Installation file name is VS2015CommunityAzurePack.
Don't do it if you use VS 12. I've got a lot of problem and it took quite a lot time to fix it.
When you change your references to "copy local=true" do it only for System.Web references.